# how get response with curl

Tags: php, api, curl, redirect

I am trying to POST to an api, it must respond with a json that contains a url and an id.
I try to POST the api as follows:

```
  public function send_payment_info( ){
       $data = $this->to_Json();


       $url = "https://toolsmati.com/webpay-api/formularios";    
       $content = json_encode($data);
       
       $curl = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

       $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

       $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

       if ( $status != 201 ) {
           die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
       }


       curl_close($curl);

       $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
   }
```

1.-This Json should be saved in the variable $response ??.
2.- once I get the url how do I redirect the page to that url??.
3.- the function toJson contain the next code, is a valid way to send??

```
    public function to_Json (){
        $data = array(
            "monto" => $this->getMonto();
            "nombre" => $this->getNombre();
            "rut" => $this->getRut();
            "mail" => $this-> getMail();
            "telefono" => $this-> getTelefono();
            "tipoCurso" => $this-> getTipoCurso();
            "sucursal" => $this-> getSucursal();
        );
        return $data;
    }
```

I'm very new to PHP, sorry if this question seems too simple, but I can't log to see what's going on as it's a plugin that I don't have console access to.

Comment: 1) if you want, yes. You can name your variables whatever you like.  2) google "how to do a redirect using php", and 3) don't understand the question, sorry

Comment: 3)when I transform the class variables into the array, is it ok?, is valid send $data via curl ?

Comment: That depends what the remote server is expecting you to send, and in what format

Comment: But the function is badly named, because it doesn't return json, it returns a php array. Json_encode is what turns it into JSON. JSON is a text format

Comment: understand thanks.